# Why is osoto guruma in dai gokyo?

Tags: judo

My understanding is that nage-waza is grouped by factors such as difficulty of break-falling and throwing difficulty. Is there a reason `osoto guruma` is in dai gokyo while `osoto gari` is in dai ikkyo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The *gokyo* is organized around a number of pedagogical factors, including the difficulty of *ukemi*, the difficulty of the throw, the relevance of the throw, and so on. In my experience, few clubs teach according to the *gokyo*, and there are no clear answers on why a given throw is in its particular place. [Mifune even had his own *gokyo*](http://blog.akarijudo.com/2014/01/the-gokyo-kodokan-vs-mifune.html), with many throws moved to earlier or later in the sequence. Why? We don't know.

That said, `osotogari` is an easy throw to learn, or at least an easy throw to learn some version of. It's also easy to make the landing for `osotogari` to be quite pleasant. (It can also be made quite unpleasant.) `Osotogari` is also one of the most fundamental, common, high-percentage, applicable throws in judo. It is a common *tokuiwaza* among non-competitors, local competitors, and elite judoka, and one of the few common powerful *tokuiwaza* that does not require turning around like its competitors *seoinage*, *uchimata*, *taiotoshi*, or *haraigoshi*. (That list was taken from two spots in Ishikawa & Draeger's book, Judo Training Methods.)

In contrast, `osotoguruma` is an odd throw. It's not that well-suited to combination, nor is it common or applicable to a wide array of situations. It is virtually unheard of as a *tokuiwaza*. Taking the fall for it takes a bit of "judo sense", that is, understanding of how and when to take *ukemi*. It's easy to mistake for `nidan osotogari`, and the body mechanics necessary to differentiate it from that throw are fairly advanced.

All told, everything about both throws points towards putting `osotogari` at the start of any curriculum, and `osotoguruma` near the end.